# Connected and bridgeless properties of Cayley graphs (or vertex transitive graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs

a) How can we prove that a Cayley graph (or a vertex transitive graph) is connected and bridgeless?

b) It is known that a even ordered Cayley graph (or vertex transitive graph) has a perfect matching and a odd ordered Cayley graph G (or vertex transitive graph) has a perfect matching for G-v, where v is any vertex of graph G.

Is there a way to prove that the Cayley graph (or vertex transitive graph) remains connected and bridgeless even when we remove the edges corresponding to above mentioned perfect matching?

I observed that when we remove a perfect matching from a certain Cayley graph it remains connected and bridgeless, but I can't think of a way to prove it.

Actually the Cayley graph I'm considering is the Cayley graph of $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ with respect to a generating set $S=\{u,t\}$, where $|u|=3, |t|=5$. When a certain perfect matching is removed the graph stays connected and bridgeless. But how can I prove it?

Please help me with these questions and guide me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $Z_{4}$ with generating set $\{2\}$ is not connected.

Comment: Hmmm, yes thanks @mathworker21 I edited the question now mentioning the particular graph i observed. I want to know whether we can prove that the graph remains connected and bridgeless for any semidirect product (with any automorphism) when we remove a particular perfect matching

Comment: Any approach by using the properties of the graph or something?

Comment: @mathworker21 $\{2\}$ does not generate $\mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't know what words you want me to use. I think a Cayley graph is a pair $(G,S)$ of a group $G$ and a symmetric set $S$ not containing $0$ (which i call the "generating set"), with $x$ connected to $y$ iff $x-y \in S$. Are you saying that a Cayley graph must have $\langle S \rangle = G$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I've always considered that assumption to be part of the usual definition. Upon looking further, Wikipedia does assume that $S$ generates $G$, but MathWorld does not, so I guess it's not as clear-cut as I thought.

Comment: @MishaLavrov do you like $e^{\sqrt{\log x}}$ because of the best known lower bound in Roth's theorem

Comment: Thanks a lot @mathworker21

Comment: and thanks a lot @MishaLavrov  do you'll have a suggestion for me to proceed in this?